# A generating function for ordered Bell numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $S(n,k)$ be a Stirling number of the second kind. Then define
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n k! \cdot S(n,k)
$$
is known as either the $n^{th}$ Fubini number or the $n^{th}$ ordered Bell number.

I know that $a_n$ satisfies the following recurrence:
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a_{n-k}
$$
and that 
$$
\frac{1}{2-e^x}=f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
is the exponential generating function. I am attempting to derive this generating function and if I can prove the following convolution
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_ka_{n-k} = \frac{a_{n+1}+a_n}{2}
$$
then I can show that $f(x)$ satisfies 
$$
2f^2(x)-f(x) = f'(x)
$$
and conclude that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2-e^x}.
$$

Does anyone know of a combinatorial proof or some other basic approach to prove the convolution? The only thing I can find requires the manipulation of lots of Fubini polynomials which I would like to avoid as the consequence is not immediate or trivial.

Comment: The EGF appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421886/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given $a_0=1$ and $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a_{n-k}$$ for $n>0$.
Now add $a_n$ to both sides to get $$2a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_{n-k}$$ for $n>0$ as well. Translating this to generating functions:
$$-1 + 2f(x) = e^xf(x)$$ leads to $$\frac1{2-e^x}=f(x).$$

Comment: Wow. I am an idiot! Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to know any additional recurrence or functional relation in order to derive the exponential generating function (egf) $A=A(x)$ of $a_n$ here. All  you need is some [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/book.pdf), part A (also see the book's [website](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html)). What you are counting here is the number of ways to put $n$ distinct balls into any possible number of distinct nonempty boxes. Let $n$ range over all nonnegative integers. Now you're just looking at ways to put distinct balls into an arbitrary-length sequence (possibly empty) of distinct nonempty boxes. Let $B=B(x)$ be the egf for number of ways of putting distinct balls into $1$ nonempty box. Then we have
$$
B=e^x-1 \quad \text{and} \quad A=\frac{1}{1-B}=\frac{1}{1-(e^x-1)}=\frac{1}{2-e^x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge0$, let
\begin{equation}\label{Fubini-No.Dfn}
  F_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!S(n,k),
\end{equation}
where $S(n,k)$, which can be generated by the exponential function
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty S(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{equation*}
and can be computed by the explicit formula
\begin{equation*}
S(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{\ell=1}^k(-1)^{k-\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\ell^{n},
\end{equation*}
denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind.
One calls these numbers $F_n$ the Fubini numbers in the paper [1] below, ordered Bell numbers in the paper [2], or geometric numbers in the paper [3] below.

A Fubini number $F_n$ has been interpreted in the papers [2, 3] combinatorially: it counts all the possible set partitions of an $n$ element set such that the order of the blocks matters. In the paper [2], the Fubini numbers $F_n$ were connected with preference arrangements and the recursion for $F_n$ was derived. In the papers [2, 4] below, the exponential generating function
\begin{equation}\label{Fubini-Num-Eq}
\frac{1}{2-e^t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n\frac{t^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
and an asymptotic estimate for $F_n$ were established.

References

1. M. E. Dasef and S. M. Kautz, *Some sums of some importance*, College Math. J. **28** (1997), 52--55.
2. O. A. Gross, *Preferential arrangements*, Amer. Math. Monthly **69** (1962), 4--8; available online at https://doi.org/10.2307/2312725.
3. S. M. Tanny, *On some numbers related to the Bell numbers*, Canad. Math. Bull. **17** (1974/75), no. 5, 733--738; available online at https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1974-132-8.
4. R. D. James, *The factors of a square-free integer*, Canad. Math. Bull. **11** (1968), 733--735; available online at https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1968-089-7.
5. F. Qi, *Determinantal expressions and recurrence relations for Fubini and Eulerian polynomials*, Journal of Interdisciplinary Mathematics **22** (2019), no. 3, 317--335; available online at https://doi.org/10.1080/09720502.2019.1624063.